# Is a std::vector<T> movable if T is not movable?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, move-semantics

I am getting a crash when trying to move a `std::vector<T>` where `T` is clearly not movable (no move constructor/assignment operator was defined, and it contains internal pointers)

But why would the move functions of vector want to call the move functions of `T`? It should not be necessary.

So my question from the title: Is a `std::vector<T>` movable if `T` is not movable?

Comment: *"no move constructor/assigment operator was defined, and it contains internal pointers"* There could be an implicitly-defined move constructor, if there's no user-declared copy ctor/assigment-op and no user-declared dtor.

Comment: Post code that reproduces the crash.

Comment: It would be very helpful to have a *minimal* example of failing code. Also, what kind of *crash* do you get? (I guess a segfault.) Can you debug into it?

Comment: If your C++ implementation does not implement [the resolution of Library Working Group Defect Report 2103](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2103), then `std::vector<T>` will be movable if and only if `T` is movable. `static_assert(std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int>>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value,"Not compliant with DR2103.");` will diagnose the problem.

Comment: @dyp : there is a user copy ctor/assigment-op and destructor, of course, since there is an underlying pointer data.

Comment: @Cory Nelson ,Ieemes : I'm not asking to solve the crash. Please keep focused on the question which is precise, thanks

Comment: @galinette It's nice that you take that for granted :) I regularly see violations of the rule of three/five.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Yes, `std::vector<T>` is movable even if `T` is not movable.  The left side merely takes ownership from the vector on the right, no elements are touched. (With one exception, listed in #2)
2. The move assignment of a `vector` would only call the move constructor or move assignment of `T` if the and their allocators compare as equal and the left side's allocator's `propagate_on_container_move_assignment` is `false`.  (Note that if your move constructor might throw or doesn't exist, the copy constructor will be used instead)  However, it is unlikely that you are encountering either of these.

   Reworded: if `propagate_on_container_move_assignment` is `true` (it usually is), then the `vector` is always movable, and does so without touching individual elements.  If it's `false`, but the allocators compare equal, the vector will be moved without touching individual elements.  If it's false and the allocators compare inequal, the individual elements will be transferred.  If a nothrow move assignment exists, that's used.  Otherwise, if a copy constructor exists, that's used.  Otherwise the throwing move assignment is used.  If it's neither movable nor copiable, then that's undefined behavior.
3. Having no move assignment operator defined, and the class containing internal pointers, does *not* mean your class is not movable.  In fact, it sounds like the compiler thinks it *is* movable.  If you want to disable moves, use `T(T&&) = delete;` and `T& operator=(T&&) =delete`, but I don't recommend that.  Instead, add a correctly working move constructor and move assignemnt.  They tend to be easy, and quite useful.

Comment: `select_on_container_copy_construction` is used for copies, which works a little differently, but you're right that I'm uncertain for the rules on copy construction.   Since the copy constructor is only called when the allocators are the same type, the ownership of the whole array is guaranteed to be safely transferable, so no element moves.

Comment: Psyduck-Confusion: successful. dyp -3 comments.

Comment: For move assignment: If `allocator_type::propagate_on_container_move_assignment` is `std::true_type` the allocator of the destination container is move assigned from the allocator of the source container. If it is `std::false_type` and the allocators compare equal, then the container guts are moved from source container to destination container and the allocators left untouched. If it is `std::false_type` and the allocators don't compare equal, the destination container allocates new elements and move constructs them individually from the source elements.

Comment: The fact that "allocators compare equal" is a runtime property implies that `std::vector<T>` is movable for non-movable `T` if and only if `allocator_type::propagate_on_container_move_assignment` is `std::true_type`.

Comment: @Casey: Not quite.  If `propagate_on_container_move_assignment` is false, and the containers compare inequal, and the type is not movable... oh my, there's a whole edge case I completely forgot about!  Basically the only time a vector isn't movable is if `propagate_on_container_move_assignment` is false the type is noncopiable and nonmovable, and the allocators compare different.  Hmm.  That last is a runtime property, not sure how this works in that case...

Comment: Oh, § 23.2.1 says that's undefined behavior.  container move assignment "Requires: If `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value` is `false`, `T` is `MoveInsertable` into `std::vector<T>` and `MoveAssignable`."

Comment: @MooingDuck As it would really have to be: even if the allocator comparison always returns true, the dead code for the false branch (that moves individual elements) would still need to be well-formed.

Comment: Notable aside: `std::allocator<int>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment` is `std::true_type` in [libstdc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99e62c4609487e49) and [libc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a252a1167bbad6a), but `std::false_type` in [VS2013](http://rextester.com/STE12578). Neither way conforms to C++11, which declares no such member for `std::allocator`, but N3936 does specify it as a `typedef` for `true_type`. Must have been a DR in there somewhere.

Comment: Found it: [the resolution of LWG DR 2103](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2103) specifies `std::allocator<T>` to be `std::true_type`.

Comment: I wonder why VS defined it as false, that's just weird.  I can't think of any advantages to doing it that way...

Comment: I tried to delete move ctor/assignment, and compilation fails on simple allocations such as : t = T(string); since when is the compiler using move semantics for a simple allocation of a constructed value? This could break old c++99 code if a faulty default move ctor is used?

Comment: @galinette: `T t = ...;` has always required that either a copy or move constructor exists, but then is not used.  That's nothing new, I know it was in C++03, and it was probably in C++99.

Comment: But I have a copy constructor! I have just deleted T(T&&) as you proposed and simple allocation T t=T(params) fails since then.

Comment: This is also in contradiction with the default move ctor rules : as I have user copy ctor, assignment operator, and destructor, there should not be a default move ctor. But if I delete it, compilation fails with "use of deleted function"

Comment: @galinette: it should not be doing that.  I'd have to see a test case to figure out what's going on in your code though.  It sounds like the compiler thinks the copy constructor doesn't exist...

Comment: @Duck : See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000243/c-default-move-constructor-compilation-issues

Comment: Well, I added the proper move ctor/operator= and now moving the vector works without crashing. I use no custom allocator. I don't understand and I don't like not understanding...

Answer (score 8):

Table 99 in [container.requirements.general] of n3797 about "Allocator-aware container requirements" says about move construction:

> *Requires:* move construction of `A` shall not exit via an exception.

Where `A` is the allocator type. It does not require *MoveInsertable* for the value type.

The time complexity requirement is: *"constant"*, btw.

---

`std::vector` typically stores some pointers plus the allocator. When move-constructing a `std::vector`, only pointers and the allocator have to be moved. The elements don't need to be touched.

Comment: It's more complicated for move *assignment*, see Mooing Duck's answer.